# How to manage bandwidth and JS loading?

Tags: javascript, ajax, import

i have an issue i don't really know how to control.

I have a server where i host a bunch of JS files that i let external websites to import.

My issue is that every time that a user changes page on the same website, he's asking again my server for the same JS file, therefore my outgoing bandwidth is exponentially increasing.

I do not have control over apache on the websites that ask for my JS files.

Is there a way i can have people import the JS file once per session, caching it on their browser for a certain amount of time?

In other cases the websites incorporates a .js file (hosted on my server) and that JS file, once loaded, starts many ajax calls (getScripts) in order to import other JS files himself.

I'm looking for a solution for caching those files having a way to control if the script needs to ask for them again or not, since this is consuming a lot of bandwidth i'd like to spare.

thanks!

Comment: Apache should be doing cache just like you want. Are you sure it's not? Otherwise I don't think you can solve this without dealing with Apache.

Comment: Since you're not in control of the cache on the client, I don't believe you're going to be able to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

in fact there was an answer to this, at least regarding the dynamically loaded JS files.
You can set the parameter "cache: true" in the ajax calls from jQuery. This way the script will just be taken from cache if present.
Technically this solved my issue.